# How to resolve 'Compiled without: Available nsock engines' message in Nmap & display open ports?

Tags: kali-linux, nmap

I'm using Nmap in Kali Linux & trying to scan the top 100 ports for the given IP. When entered the below command, it does not display any open ports. But gives the 'Compiled without: Available nsock engines: epoll poll select' message.

`nmap -A -F -T1 ip_address -V`

[image]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

There’s nothing to resolve: the two messages are separate. “Compiled without:” means that there is no feature missing in your `nmap`. “Available nsock engines: epoll poll select” lists the available nsock engines.

The problem with your command is that `-V` disables everything else: it only shows the version of `nmap` and its compilation options, it doesn’t scan. If you remove `-V` you’ll see `nmap` scanning.

Your option selection is somewhat contradictory too, `-F` asks for a fast scan but `-A` asks for a thorough scan. Start with `-F` on its own, and change the options as necessary depending on the results of the initial scan.